# Problema al ejecutar cpp en Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Buenas a todos,

he instalado el paquete Linter para que Atom me muestre los errores de sintaxis en mi código. 
Pero hay un error que no hay forma de eliminar, y es este (compile el cpp cual sea).

¿Saben cómo podría eliminar ese error en Atom?
Uso mac.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias

Comment: por lo que veo parece que alguna función tiene un parámetro (argumento) sin uso `argument unused`.

Comment: puedes poner el código para ver si podemos ayudarte

Comment: Perdonadme, ya está solucionado, hay que incluir en configuración de linter gcc en "Flags" la opción de -fmax-errors=0 y desaparece ese error.